# Make opacity using css3 transition for each image separately

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to change the opacity on mouseover for each image separately using a CSS3 transition.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="gallary">
     <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
     <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
     <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
     <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
     <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
     <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
     <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
#gallary img{
    opacity:1;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in;
}

#gallary:hover img{
    opacity:.5;
}
```

The selector occurs for all images inside a div with the id "gallary". How can I make the opacity change for each image separately on mouseover?

Here's a sample:  http://jsfiddle.net/TJeHX/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#gallary:hover img {
```

->

```
#gallary img:hover {
```

You current definition changes opacity of whole "gallary" container and therefore, for all images.